# preg_replace to change text start with '@' and end with '@\n'

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have s string such as this :

```
@
String mystr = "test@example.com"
String mystr = test@@@@::example.com;
@
```

i want to change first '@' to [code] and secont last '@' to [/code].

after first and last '@' we have space or '\n'.

this code is not work for me :

```
$text = preg_replace('#[@](.|)(.*?)[@\n]#',"'<pre>$2</pre>'",$text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to consider the newlines in the subject string, you need to add to add the 'm' [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the regexp and maybe 's' too.

This snippet does what you're asking:

```
<?php
$test = <<<END
@
String mystr = "test@example.com"
String mystr = test@@@@::example.com;
@

END;

echo preg_replace('/@\s(.*)@\s/sm', "<code>\n$1</code>\n", $test);
?>
```

Output:

```
<code>
String mystr = "test@example.com"
String mystr = test@@@@::example.com;
</code>
```

If there's more than one pair of '@' in the input string, then the regexp should include the 'U' modifier:

```
<?php
$test = <<<END
@
String mystr = "test@example.com"
String mystr = test@@@@::example.com;
@

@
String mystr2 = "test2@example.com"
String mystr2 = test@@@@2::example.com;
@

END;

echo preg_replace('/@\s(.*)@\s/smU', "<code>\n$1</code>\n", $test);
?>
```

Output:

```
<code>
String mystr = "test@example.com"
String mystr = test@@@@::example.com;
</code>

<code>
String mystr2 = "test2@example.com"
String mystr2 = test@@@@2::example.com;
</code>
```

Comment: very goo.thanks.but if i have more than 1 code in string,it merges both of them together!

Comment: @user1829014 I've updated my answer. If I understand you correctly, the second part covers the case you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say easiest way is non-regexp way:

```
$splitted = str_split($your_string, "@");
$first = array_shift($splitted);
$last = array_pop($splitted);

$result = "[code]" . implode("@", $splitted) . "[/code]";
```

Or something similar, whatever you see best.

Comment: thanks.i have another thing in my string.and regex is the best way to do.but this way is not work